# Перенос строк

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня есть такой html:

```
<div id="a">
 <span>Я</span>
 <span>люблю</span>
 <span>печеньки</span>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Когда я кликаю на кнопку, выполняется такой скрипт:

```
$('div#b').html($('div#a').children('span').text())
```

У меня возникла такая проблема.
Оно в итоге переносит текст так:

```
<div id="b">Я люблю печеньки</div>
```

А как мне сделать, чтобы оно переносило так:

```
<div id="b">Я
люблю
печеньки</div>
```

Надеюсь, суть проблемы поняли.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если, кроме span-элементов, ничего в первом блоке больше нет, то можно сделать просто:

```
$('div#b').html('<pre>' + $('div#a').text() + '</pre>');
```

Если там присутствуют и другие элементы, то так:

```
var divA = $('div#a').clone();
$(':not(span)',divA).remove();
$('div#b').html('<pre>' + divA.text() + '</pre>');
```

Если же тег <pre> не устраивает, то переносы делаем с помощью <br>

```
var fStr = $('div#a span').map(function(i, el){
    return $(el).text() + '<br>';
}).get().join('');
$('div#b').html(fStr);
```

Последний [вариант в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/2wd3s4kw/).

Comment: Ну в общем я понял. Но мне надо что бы оно переносило не визуально, а переносило внутри кода.

Comment: О, все. Подправил под себя больше код, заработал.)